# Where is ARM TrustZone api?

Tags: arm, embedded, cpu-architecture, trustzone

I read in trustzone_security_whitepaper.pdf, chapter 5.5 The TrustZone API,

```
>To encourage the development of security solutions ARM have produced a 
>standardized software API, called the TrustZone API (TZAPI), which defines 
>a software interface which client applications running in the rich operating
>environment can use to interact with a security environment.
```

and 5.5.1 API availability

```
>"The TrustZone API can be downloaded for free from the ARM website"
```

I searched the arm website but didn't found the entry to TrustZone api list or manuals?

Comment: The TrustZone is a security extension. [ARM Security Technology: Building a Secure System using TrustZone Technology](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.prd29-genc-009492c/PRD29-GENC-009492C_trustzone_security_whitepaper.pdf). Also see [arm reference manual trustzone](https://www.google.com/search?q=arm+reference+manual+trustzone).

Comment: @jww Yes, I have read this document. But as I edited in my post, I saw ARM provided a download of the interface for TZAPI. Please refer to 5.5.1

Comment: @wason Asking for off-site resources is off-topic. You are still required to have a fair amount of Google Magic skills for that :) There is something [in this forum](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/tiva_arm/f/908/t/311254). The specs are free to download but you need to register. 10minutesmails may be handy. I don't know if that is the official ARM document (I also believe that the official documentation must be explicitly requested to ARM).

Comment: @Bloom, yes, you're right. After signing in, I found it in download menu left side of my ARM Self Service.

Comment: I agree with the answer here, Arm seems to officially support the GlobalPlatform APIs for communicating between REE and TEE, as you can see here, it is even included in their official graphic: https://developer.arm.com/ip-products/security-ip/trustzone/trustzone-for-cortex-a
Thus GP Internal/Client APIs are used, and no TZAPI is needed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know TrustZone API (TZAPI) is deprecated.
One of the reference document is [ARM SMC Calling Convention](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0028b/ARM_DEN0028B_SMC_Calling_Convention.pdf).

If you look for a specific Trustzone API then it really depends what you want to build.
If you want to build a Trusted Application then have a look at TEE (Trusted Execution Environment).